# How to make selected of the clicked link in Mat-Toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

As far as I know(from bootstrap navbar),on the header we need to use `routerLinkActive="active"` to make any clicked element as selected.I tried to implement same logic for Material Toolbar but failed.Also checked other possible solutions such as `routerLinkActive="primary" etc` but failed too.

Here is my HTML for Toolbar below

```
 <mat-toolbar color="primary">

        <div fxHide.gt-xs>
                <button mat-icon-button routerLink="/settings">
                        <mat-icon>build</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-icon-button routerLink="/">
                        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
                    </button>
           </div> 
                <div fxFlex fxLayout fxHide.xs>
                        <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="10px" class="navigation-items">
                            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/settings" >Settings</a></li>
                            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a style="cursor:pointer" routerLink="/">Home</a></li>                   
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                           <div fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="flex-end">
                           <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="10px" class="navigation-items">
                                   <li>Weather</li>
                            </ul>
                           </div> 

</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: The only attribute that support is `color="---"` as per the official documentation, you will need another workaround probably some hacky thing. GL

Comment: If you use `routerLinkActive` without mat-toolbar does this `routerLinkActive` styling work?

Comment: You can maybe use this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i4bcc1) to replicate your issue. Your syntax is correct, there could be something happening with you router configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes in your template

```
 <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="10px" class="navigation-items">
   <li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/settings" >Settings</a></li>
   <li><a style="cursor:pointer" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/">Home</a></li>                   
 </ul>
```

Comment: Technically you absolutely can have `routerLinkActive` on elements such as `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

On router outlet we can get template ref using outlet directive like this

```
<router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
```

Then you can use template ref to get route path. Using that you can set ngClass dynamically

```
<ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="10px" class="navigation-items">
<li [ngClass]="{o?.isActivated && o.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path === '' : 'active'} "><a style="cursor:pointer" routerLink="/">Home</a></li>         
 </ul>
```

[Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)

Comment: Gives me error like that : Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 3 in [{o?.isActivated && o.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path === '' : 'active'} ] in ng:///AppModule/HeaderComponent.html@13:43 ("mat-accent"><a routerLink="/settings" >Settings</a></li>

Comment: can you create stackblitz?